# Python Selenium errors started showing up

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, error-handling

Earlier today I was able to access the website below and run my automated script using Python Selenium.

A few hours later, after taking a break, using the exact same script I get the following errors. Anyone know why that is? I didn't change anything on my end. Could the website have made changes on their end? I replaced the website name with XXXXX's.

```
[0615/185824.599:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at isVisible (https://www.XXXXXX:207:32)
    at showAllTimesEnd (https://www.XXXXXX:199:18)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://www.XXXXXX:328:4)
    at l (https://www.XXXXXX.com/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29375)
    at c (https://www.XXXXXX.com/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29677) undefined", source: https://www.XXXXXX.com/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js (2)
[0615/185824.619:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined", source: https://www.XXXXXX.com/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js (2)
```